# Example of binary trees with maximum rotation distance

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees, search-trees, binary-search-trees

In the 1988 paper [Rotation Distance, Triangulations, and Hyperbolic Geometry](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sleator/papers/rotation-distance.pdf), Sleator, Tarjan and Thurston show that for any pair of $n$-node binary trees, the maximum [rotation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_rotation#Rotation_distance) between them is $2n-6$ for all $n \ge 11$.

They also claim that this bound is tight for sufficiently large $n$. I see how they achieved the upper bound of $2n-6$ rotations but I am now trying to understand their proof of the lower bound. To the best of my understanding, their argument relies on triangulating a polyhedron and looking at volumes in hyperbolic space.

I'm having trouble connecting these fairly technical mathematical claims back to actual binary trees. In particular, what would be a concrete example of two binary trees (or families of binary trees) which meet this lower bound and actually require $2n-6$ rotations to transform one tree into the other?